# Getting Started with ANTLR4 and C++

Tags: c++, macos, g++, antlr4

First time question asker here, so bear with me. So I've got a grammar file from the grammars repository that I'm trying to use with C++. (Developing on macOS). I have no issue generating the lexer and parser using ANTLR. But after that, I have no idea how to run/use the resulting .cpp and .h files. I understand that there is an antlr runtime that I must download, and I have done so from the antlr.org website (gives me two folders, antlr4-runtime and lib), but my novice understanding of C++ seems to be preventing me from getting any further than that. How do I use the runtime to work with these files? I'm not using an IDE, just g++ from the command line. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Asking for complete tutorials on a library like Antlr is a bit out of scope for Stack Overflow, but here are some basic resources: https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-antlr-cpp/ and https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/cpp-target.md

Answer (score 4):

I found this guide helpful: [Getting Started with ANTLR in C++](https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-antlr-cpp/). (Ah, saw @ggorlen's comment after.)

If you scroll down on that page to a little past halfway, there's a section titled **How to Use ANTLR in C++**. I think that's where you are.

I'll copy that example over as SO generally prefers this. Say this is your main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "antlr4-runtime/SceneLexer.h"
#include "antlr4-runtime/SceneParser.h"
#include "ImageVisitor.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace antlr4;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open("input.scene");

    ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
    SceneLexer lexer(&input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    SceneParser parser(&tokens);    
    SceneParser::FileContext* tree = parser.file();
    ImageVisitor visitor;
    Scene scene = visitor.visitFile(tree);
    scene.draw();
    return 0;
}
```

You want to include your lexer and parser .h (header) files instead of the SceneLexer/Parser in the example, and also include antlr4-runtime.h. Then run g++ on all your .cpp files, *e.g.*

```
$ g++ main.cpp YourLexer.h YourParser.h
```